# I can't add foreign key constraint in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working on small chat application using Laravel, I'm getting a migration error:

this is my migration :

```
Schema::create('chats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->integer('from_id');
            $table->integer('to_id');
            $table->text('message');

            $table->foreign('from_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('to_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Error :

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `chats` add constraint `chats_from_id_foreign` foreign key (`from_id`) references `users` (`id`))
```

I refreshed and I recreate my database, but still have the same error

Comment: the type of the foreign key has to match exactly to the type it is referencing

Comment: @lagbox  how ? can you help more please

Comment: how did you define the `id` field on `users` in the migration?

Comment: by default is `$table->id();`

Comment: that would be creating an unsigned big integer, not an integer ... you have to match that

Comment: @lagbox  how ? can share the code please

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types  `unsignedBigInteger`

Answer (score 2):

You must follow the same datatype with unsigned for foreign key. By default laravel uses `bigint` so you must use `unsignedBigInteger`

```
Schema::create('chats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('from_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('to_id');
            $table->text('message');

            $table->foreign('from_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('to_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the reference key must have the same column type. But laravel has `foreignId()` method that same as default id type. For laravel 6++, the default id type is unsigned big integer, before laravel 6, the default id has unsigned integer type.

so you need to change

```
$table->integer('from_id');
$table->integer('to_id');
```

to

```
$table->foreignId('from_id');
$table->foreignId('to_id');
```

Another alternative way, just use `foreignIdFor()` method to create column and add foreign key in single line.

```
$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\User::class,'from_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\User::class,'to_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```